IDE unable to render call graph for member functions of classes referenced through smart pointers
When I declare a smart pointer in a class, the IDE has issues rendering the call graph when it's used in one of its member functions. This is what I mean:
classX.hpp
class classX: 
{
       std::unique_ptr<ClassB> pClassB;
       .......
}

src.cpp
classX::myFunc {

.....
.....
pClassB->itsFunc(); // IDE unable to create call graph for 'itsFunc' here
.....
.....
}

I believe this is because the parser doesn't understand what pClassB is on its own. Is there anything I can do to fix this? Perhaps download the STL (or at least the relevant header files)?
I have a deeply nested design and it would be great if I could fix this.

pClassB-->itsFunc(); is not correct C++. Make sure to accurately depict your error and add debug information (e.g. did the tool report any errors).  Also before you start modifying existing code : Add unit test!

@PepijnKramer done. Nonetheless my intention was to show the kind of statements that seem to confuse the IDE. For instance, if I ask vscode or source insight to show me the call stack starting from that statement, it doesn't show anything.
